# iPhone: app crashing when scrolling UITableView up to 60+ custom cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have search the web many times for the same question and also got many relavent answers but none of them resolved my problem.
Here is the problem: I am having a UITableView with UISearchBar on its top.As the users searches for particular word,the UITableView is filled with custom cells.
It works fine in the simulator.The problem is with the device,I mean iPad.
Now when the tableview is having almost 40-50 cells,it works fine even when the user scrolls. But if the tableView contains 60+ cells and user scrolls to,say 55 onwards,app crashes without giving any error. I have set NSZoombie Enabled. I have already debugged the app many times but no results.

Comment: Profile your app in instruments. If it crashes on the device and not the simulator, and the crash occurs with a large number of cells, you're probably running out of memory, so you either have a leak or you aren't reusing cells properly.

Answer (score 1):

profile your app and see if you use too much memory or not.
also you can see memory warnings from applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning method of your appdelegate, just implement it and put a breakpoint to the entrance. 
if there is a problem with reusing of the cells, you might be allocating too much cells and exceeding the memory limits.

Comment: Yes, The app is using heavy images so,definitely there are memory issues. I have already plugged an alert view in the applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning method of app delegate.Sometimes it gives messages of low memory but most of the times it crashes without giving any warning.